# Null pointer exception in libgdx

Tags: java, libgdx

I get the error

> Task :desktop: Desktop Launcher. main() FAILED
> Exception in thread "main" java. lang. Exception In Initializer Error

```
at com.mygdx.game.Cat.Initextures(Cat.java:23)
at com.mygdx.game.Cat.<init>(Cat.java:20)
at com.mygdx.game.TacoCat.<init>(TacoCat.java:18)
at com.mygdx.game.desktop.DesktopLauncher.main(DesktopLauncher.java:10)
```

Caused by: java .lang. Null Pointer Exception
at com.mygdx.game.Resources.(Resources.java:7)
... 4 more

Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException

I have two files
Resources

```
package com.mygdx.game;

import com.badlogic.gdx.Gdx;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.Texture;

public class Resources {
    public static Texture catTexture = new Texture(Gdx.files.internal("cat1.png"));
}
```

Cat

```
package com.mygdx.game;

import com.badlogic.gdx.Gdx;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.TextureData;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.Animation;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.TextureRegion;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.Texture;


public class Cat {
    public int x,y,width,height;
    public boolean onGrond;
    public Texture catTexture;
    public Cat(int xpos,int ypos,boolean onGround){
        x = xpos;
        y = ypos;
        this.onGrond = onGround;
        Initextures();
    }
    public void Initextures(){
        catTexture = Resources.catTexture;
        width = Resources.catTexture.getWidth();
        height = Resources.catTexture.getHeight();
    }
    public void draw(SpriteBatch batch){
       batch.draw(catTexture,x,y);
    }
```

Any help would be amazing and thank you in advance

Comment: it looks like Resources.catTexture is null - you should debug to find out why

Comment: I'm not an expert on textures, but they are closely linked to opengl. It's possible that you shouldn't use static initialisers like this to create textures, perhaps some aspects of opengl need to be initialised first. I would recommend moving your initialisation of catTexture into the create method of libgdx and see what happens. In fact, initialising textures this way is bad for many reasons, I suggest you read about opengl context and the lifecycle of an android application.

Comment: Yes, if you are a beginner with libGDX and/or Java, DO NOT use `static` references with libGDX. Only do so after you are intimately familiar with the libGDX lifecycle, how and when static references are made, and what it means for a libGDX class to be `Disposable`.

Answer (score 1):

At the point when `catTexture` is initialized the `Gdx.files` member is not yet initialized, so it's null and that is what is causing you problem.

I am guessing that your `TacoCat` is extending `ApplicationAdapter` or `Application`, and you need to override the `create` method and load your resources (or instanciate your `Cat` object) in that method.

This is because the **libGDX** runtime needs to initialize first and things like texture loading must run on the OpenGL thread.

In your `TacoCat` class **don't do** this

```
public class TacoCat extends ApplicationAdapter {
  private Cat cat;

  public TacoCat() {
    cat = new Cat();
  }
}
```

Do this;

```
public class TacoCat extends ApplicationAdapter {
  private Cat cat;

  @Override
  public void create() {
    cat = new Cat();
  }
}
```

Note that you don't have to manually call `create`, the **libGDX** runtime will call that for you.